# problems with unit test in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing

I'm trying to run my simple UserTest

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  fixtures :users

  test "user attributes must not be empty" do
    user = users(:valid_user)
    assert user.invalid?
    assert user.errors[:nome].any?
    assert user.errors[:cognome].any?
    assert user.errors[:localita].any?
    assert user.errors[:provincia].any?
    assert user.errors[:nazione].any?
    assert user.errors[:cap].any?
    assert user.errors[:indirizzo].any?
    assert user.errors[:civico].any?
    assert user.errors[:telefono].any?
    assert user.errors[:mail].any?
    assert user.errors[:username].any?
    assert user.errors[:password].any?
  end

end
```

with this users.yaml

```
valid_user:
  nome: prova
  cognome: prova
  localita: prova
  provincia: prova
  nazione: prova
  cap: 00000
  indirizzo: strada di prova
  civico: 1
  telefono: 1111111111
  mail: prova@prova.com
  username: prova
  password: prova
```

but it returns this error:

> Loaded suite
>   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
>   Started F Finished in 0.182523 seconds.
>
> 1) Failure: test_user_attributes_must_not_be_empty(UserTest)
>   [../unit/user_test.rb: 10]: Failed assertion, no message given.
>
> 1 tests, 2 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, Failed assertion is

```
assert user.errors[:nome].any?
```

which means that there are no errors on attribute :nome

why are you asserting that there should be errors on that attribute is a complete mystery to me

maybe you wanted to use `errors[:nome].none?` ?

Comment: thanks for your answer, now it works well, i'm new with unit test in rails and i'm trying to learn it. Thanks again

Comment: glad i could help you, as a rule of thumb - you don't have to re-test general rails functionality(if you have validations on your model they will fail upon saving it) and try to use more self-explanatory assert methods like assert_equal and friends - that will make tests read much better and you will spot such mistakes immediately. good luck!